# Mocking out global variables prior to importing a module?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to do unit testing for an aws lambda function that uses environment variables to create some global objects. When I try to import my local copy of the lambda into my unit test file, I will get a key error for 'LOG_LEVEL'.

```
import boto3
import logging
import os

log_level = os.environ['LOG_LEVEL']
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(eval(log_level))


def handler(event, context):
    ...some code...
```

and inside my testing file:

```
import unittest
from myModule import *
from moto import mock_dynamodb2, mock_s3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
```

Is there anyway I can mock out the os.environ value before I import into my testing file?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment variable in your test function

```
def test_log_level():
    os.environ['LOG_LEVEL'] = 'DEBUG'
    ...
```